# Finding the polynomials (or power series) $p_n(x)$ such that $2\int x^ne^{x^2}dx = p_n(x) e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, recurrence-relations, power-series

By using integration by parts, one can obtain the following equation

> $$2\int x^ne^{x^2}dx=x^{n-1}e^{x^2}-(n-1)\int x^{n-2}e^{x^2}dx .$$

A recursive formula for $\int x^ne^{x^2}dx$ that works if and only if $n$ is odd because:

$$2\int xe^{x^2}dx=e^{x^2}$$

Now, upon using this formula, I obtained the following polynomials:

$$2\int x^1e^{x^2}dx=(1)e^{x^2}$$

$$2\int x^3e^{x^2}dx=(x^2-1)e^{x^2}$$

$$2\int x^5e^{x^2}dx=(x^4-2x^2+2)e^{x^2}$$

$$2\int x^7e^{x^2}dx=(x^6-3x^4+6x^2-6)e^{x^2}$$

The solution is always in the form of a polynomial multiplied by $e^{x^2}$.  I was wondering if this polynomial could have an easy solution in terms of the exponent on the left that may be easily found:

$$p_n(x)=x^{n-1}-(n-1)x^{n-3}+?x^{n-5}+\dots$$

Any easy pattern?

Then, I would like to see if this can be made into a continuous polynomial that works for even $n$ so that I may evaluate $\int e^{x^2}dx$ as a polynomial multiplied by $e^{x^2}$, which I can imagine this polynomial will have an infinite amount of terms, a power series.

$$\int x^0e^{x^2}dx=x^{-1}e^{x^2}+x^{-3}e^{x^2}+?x^{-5}e^{x^2}+\dots$$

I know the solution can not be shown in a finite amount of elementary functions, as shown on other related questions, but couldn't this work?

> Is there an easy form of my power series?  After that, apply this to try and evaluate $\int x^0e^{x^2}dx$.  Determine if the formula works for the result.

Comment: Do not say "polynomial with an infinite amount of terms". Instead say "power series".

Comment: It just occurred to me, should I edit this question so that it may easily be found for someone searching for the integral of $e^{x^2}$?

Answer (score 4):

Computing one more example is suggestive:
$$2 \int x^9 e^{x^2} dx = (x^8-4x^6+12x^4-24x^2+24)e^{x^2},$$ and we can see that the ratios between successive coefficients are $-4, -3, -2, 1, -1$, leading to the guess
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{2 \int x^{2 k + 1} e^{x^2} dx = \left[ \sum_{i = 0}^k (-1)^{k - i} \frac{k!}{i!} x^{2k} \right] e^{x^2}}}$$ (for integers $k \geq 0$).
We can prove that this formula holds for general $k$ using a standard induction argument and the recurrence relation given in the first display equation of the question.

I do not know how to use this to derive the power series for the analogous even-exponent integrals, i.e., for $\int_0^x t^{2k} e^{t^2} dt$.

We can proceed as follows using another method to recover the power series in $x$: The power series for $$e^{-x^2} \int_0^x t^{2k} e^{t^2} dt$$ is
$$e^{-x^2} \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt \sim \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^i \frac{4^i i!}{(2i + 1)^!} x^{2 i + 1}$$
(which we can establish by writing $e^{t^2}$ as a power series, formally integrating, multiplying by the power series for $e^{-x^2}$, and proving by induction on degree that the series agree). Then, the series for a general even power is
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{e^{-x^2} \int_0^x t^{2k} e^{t^2} dt \sim \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^i \frac{4^i i!}{(2i + 1)^!} x^{2 k + 2 i + 1} }}.$$

Comment: Do you mean to say that they are equivalent?  Can I use that as if it were equivalent?

Comment: To say that what are equivalent? The expression and the power series (in the even case, say)?

Comment: Yes, is the integral and power series equivalent?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that for all $x$ the power series converges to the value of the expression on the l.h.s. of the second boxed equation.

Comment: Ok thanks.${ }$

Answer (score 4):

Assume $$\int_a^{x}t^n e^{t^2} dt = p(x) e^{x^2}$$ 
for some polynomial function $p(x)$ (you can prove this). You're looking for $p(x)$ - you can just differentiate both sides wrt x to get 
$$x^n e^{x^2}=p'(x)e^{x^2}+2xp(x)e^{x^2}$$
$e^{x^2}$ is never 0 so just divide through and you have a linear ordinary differential equation.
$$x^n=p'(x) + 2xp(x)$$
The solution to this ODE involves an incomplete gamma function:
$$p(x)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{-(n+1)}{2}}}{2}\Gamma(\frac{1+n}{2},-x^2)$$

For odd n, i.e., $m=\frac{n+1}{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$, the incomplete gamma function has a simple power series: $$\Gamma(m, -x^2)=(m-1)!e^{x^2}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{k!}$$

Hence
$$p_m(x)=\frac{(-1)^m}{2}(m-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{k!}$$

Comment: Wow, and this doesn't seem to be the same as Travis' answer?  I will try it out and see how it works though.

Comment: At a glance this answer looks to agree with my own; the differences are the a constant has been factored out of the sum, the factor of $2$ is effectively on the other side of the equation, and the sum is indexed differently. (+1) for the nice answer, b.t.w.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to replace $x^2$ by $-x^2$ (corresponding to multiplying $x$ by $i$).
The (physicist's) Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$ satisfy $H_0(x) = 1$, $H_1(x) = 2x$, and (Rodrigues's formula)
$$ H_n(x) e^{-x^2} = (-1)^n \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2} = - \dfrac{d}{dx} \left(H_{n-1}(x) e^{-x^2}\right)$$
Thus for $n \ge 1$, $$\int H_n(x) e^{-x^2}\;dx = - H_{n-1}(x) e^{-x^2} + C$$ 
Now you can convert between the powers $x^n$ and the Hermite polynomials
$$ \eqalign{x^n &= \dfrac{n!}{2^n} \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \dfrac{H_{n-2m}(x)}{m!(n-2m)!}\cr
H_n(x) &= n! \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \dfrac{(-1)^m}{m!(n-2m)!} (2x)^{n-2m}}$$
so that if $n$ is odd $\int x^n e^{-x^2}\; dx$ is expressed as an odd polynomial times $e^{-x^2}$, while if $n$ is even it is an even polynomial times $e^{-x^2}$ plus a multiple of $\int e^{-x^2}\; dx$.

Comment: I love all of the ideas!  And all very advanced and different, different being the most interesting part... :D  nice job  +1

Answer (score 1):

Maple says
$$
2\,\int \!{{\rm e}^{{x}^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x=
\big({x}^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}\,{x}^{-3}+\frac{3}{4}\,{x
}^{-5}
+{\frac {15}{8}}x^{-7}+\frac{105}{16}x^{-9}+O(x^{-11})\big)e^{x^2}
$$
as $x \to \infty$.